# Should the top torus of a Tesla coil be cut?

Tags: frequency, load, resonance, efficiency, tesla-coil

Dosen't the top load torus act like one turn coil in short circuit?

Doesn't it "steal" (decrease) the energy transfer to the arc?

As a load, it has an inductive reactance (1 turn solenoid.) Does this reactance affect the operation of the coil, in a constructive way or bad way? Shouldn't it have a cut (vertical slit) and a circular disc insulator inserted into it, thus our torus is now an open circuit 1 turn coil? Isn't this better? If so, then won't this insulator now act like a capacitor forming a "1 turn-coil" with the top torus an LC tank circuit with a resonance in MHz range? How does this resonance or frequency affect the tens of KHz operation of a standard Tesla coil?

Thus the question arises: Which is better: leave the top load torus standard as a short-circuited 1 turn coil, or cut it?

I'm confused, please help. Total noob. Please have mercy.

Please don't tell me the torus acts as a capacitor. I already know that. Please don't tell me it's called "top load" because it's a capacitive loading of the secondary coil. I already know these things. This is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Let's consider the torus completely filled inside with copper, and then think of it as a giant colossal thick 1 turn wire. This Wire is now a coil. A short-circuit coil. Doesn't it "grab" "steal" some of the energy in the system? Sure it will have to be in tune with the KHz resonance of the secondary, which will never happen, but that's besides the point. Is there an effect? Should the torus be cut along the poloidal direction of the torus? But then won't it form an LC tank circuit with the dielectric we place in the slit? I'm confused. Is this effect real, negligible or what?

Comment: I also remember that the higher we go in frequency, conductors become insulators (manifested as skin-effect) and insulators(dielectrics) become conductors. It's a simple english definition of reactance for dummies. But even if the inductive reactance of the "torus-1-turn-coil" is HIGH for its own SRF, won't it be LOW for a standard KHz range Tesla coil, also considering the mutual inductance between the two? I have this sense that this effect is present, but negligible, but then again, why does nobody top load torus of tesla coils are ever cut? I'm so confused and lost. I don't understand

Comment: This is an excellent question, do not apologize! Yes, technically it is a shorted turn but as mentioned in the answers its coupling with the secondary coil is very low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the top load does form a 'shorted turn', the effect of this on coil operation is minimal.

The shorted turn has low coupling with most of the secondary, and therefore the effect is fairly small.

The shorted turn has very large area and so low losses, and so dissipates little energy. Far larger losses occur in the thin wire and the thin skin-depth of the secondary winding, streamer loading, and the spark gap.

The main effect of the topload shorted turn is to increase the secondary resonant frequency slightly by reducing its inductance a little.

Some coilers do break the topload shorted turn in various ways. Some do make the cut you suggest, but round the edges so as not to cause a corona problem. Some build a topload from a broken spiral of copper pipes (I'll see if I can find a link to pictures). There's little evidence that either improves the performance of the coils in any marked way.

There is so much else on a coil that needs to be got right, that worrying about the topload shorted turn should (literally) be the last thing on your mind.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it! There is an effect, and also had the sense it's minimal (compared with other loses you mentioned, of which I totally agree). Your answer gives me some clarification, but now you raised another question in my mind, by leaving the topload as a shorted turn, how is this increasing the secondary resonant frequency? Don't Tesla Coil fans want a lower frequency because it's easier to handle and drive with IGBTs?

Comment: @NiculaeGeorgeRazvan It increases the resonant frequency because the shorted turn reduces the secondary inductance. Here we're talking a few percent, as in 'slightly'. IGBT driving wants reductions of factors of 3 to 10 from spark-gap coils, totally different orders of magnitude, so you have fatter coils with thinner wire with many many more turns to get the inductance up, and much larger toploads to get the C up.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sorry again, but let me see if I understood this correctly. If I did, then the answer to my question is to leave the torus intact (as most people do), because the SRF of the torus as a coil is very high (hundreds of MHz) in comparison to standard operating resonance(KHz) of the Tesla coil. By making a cut in the torus, I'm adding capacitance to this SRF thus lowering it. Since we are slightly lower than before (still in MHz), we are thus closer to the operating KHz frequency, thus the energy transfer is slightly better, thus the cut torus "steals" more energy than an uncut one. Am I right?

Comment: Whether cut or intact, the resonant frequency of a torus is waaaaay above that of the secondary. The cut torus will have lower losses, as the RF current will be much less through the capacitance of the cut than the continuity of the loop. We generally leave the torus intact as that's a far easier construction, looks better (execpt that segmeneted one I still can't find the link for) and works practically as well.

Comment: I'm not so convinced that the RF current will be much less through the capacitance of the cut than the continuity of the loop, because of reactance. I'm still missing a lot of info and I'm very unsure of myself. My question is does the SRF of a shorted 1 turn coil is lower or higher than a cut one? Although we are a bit offtopic, debating a tiny detail in the operation of a Tesla Coil, with negligible effects, it doesn't matter, since my goal is not a Tesla Coil but to increase my learning and understanding overall.

Comment: Whereas a cut torus would resonate like an LC - and it's very easy to do some ballpark estimate of the L and C involved, and compare those to the L and the C relevant to the Tesla operation frequency, think about what the resonant modes of a complete torus would be. It's symmetrical, so there would not be a resonance involving circulating current, which would couple to the secondary, only L and R terms. Any resonance would have to involve modes which could see a capacitance, so side to side or 'bell' modes. Try estimating the L, then seeing what the effect of a C versus short is for current.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, I think the RF current is mostly in the capacitor, as the RF voltage on the other hand is on the coil (opposite of DC behaviour). This is because of reactance, as we go higher and higher in frequency, they gradually switch places, and the loop of wire acts with high impedance, while the capacitor acts with low impedance, hence the RF current is mostly in the cap and not in the coil. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree with you that self-capacitance of a torus is side to side. A little tricky to visualize how a torus would polarize, but the point is, that the capacitance is inverse proportional with the distance between polarities, hence I reason that when I make a cut in a torus, I drastically and critically change how the torus polarizes, now charges accumulate on the edges of my cut. The distance between opposite charges has drastically decreased, thus the capacitance has increased, thus the SRF is lower. That's how I reason. I might be wrong. I don't know. I'm not sure. I'm no expert in RF theory